# Using Selenium css selector to extract data

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I did this code that returns to me a list of `li` , but I want to access to each `a` tag mentioned inside and open it , if you have any recommandation I would be very grateful

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

options = Options()

# Creating our dictionary
all_services = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Motif', 'Description'])

path = "C:/Users/Al4D1N/Documents/ChromeDriver_webscraping/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)

driver.get("https://www.mairie.net/national/acte-naissance.htm#plus")

list_of_services = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".list-images li")
```

I know that I need to iterate in each list_of_services Item , but I don't know how can I open each  `a`  tag since they all don't have classes or ids that can help me to make difference between them

Comment: What do you mean by open each a tag? Do you need the actual hrefs or only the titles?

Comment: Actually if you visit the website you will see down in the page a second section that have multiple `hrefs` , and I need to open every `<a>` tag there . and in every link opened I have to do extract specific data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to extract all of the links within the hrefs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

options = Options()

# Creating our dictionary
all_services = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Motif', 'Description'])

path = "C:/Users/Al4D1N/Documents/ChromeDriver_webscraping/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)

driver.get("https://www.mairie.net/national/acte-naissance.htm#plus")

#Get all elements in class 'list-images'
list_of_services = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("list-images")

for service in list_of_services:
    #In each element, select the atags
    atags = service.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
    for atag in atags:
        #In each atag, select the href
        href = atag.get_attribute('href')
```

Output:

```
https://www.mairie.net/national/acte-mariage.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/acte-deces.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/carte-identite.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/passeport.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/casier-judiciaire.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/demande-carte-electorale.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/cadastre-plu.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/carte-grise-en-ligne-par-internet.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/certificat-non-gage.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/permis-conduire-delivrance.htm#acte-naissance
https://www.mairie.net/national/changement-adresse.htm#acte-naissance
```

Comment: and what If I want to open each href and try to extrac specific data for each one , for example I go to the first link shown there and I do some `find_elements method`  , is there any alternatif for that ? or I need to open again with  `driver.get(href)` ?

Comment: Yes, I think the best way would be to store all hrefs in a list and then loop through that list  and call ```driver.get(href)``` or alternatively open each href in a new tab. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814991/python-selenium-loop-through-links how to handle different tabs.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: ah I didnt see your stack link , it's okay I have the solution now , thank you